# Estimate bias of perturbed Bernoulli process

Tags: probability

I have a Bernoulli process with parameter $\theta$,

$$
Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\theta),
$$

as well as a *perturbed* process:

$$
X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\theta + \varepsilon), \qquad \varepsilon \geq 0, \qquad (\theta + \varepsilon) \in [0, 1].
$$

Given realizations $\{z_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, can I estimate $\varepsilon$?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is $\in \mathbb{R}$? or a random variable?

Comment: I don't understand why people vote to close this. This question looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just have to build an estimator for $\varepsilon$. If $X_1,\cdots,X_n, Z_1,\cdots,Z_n$ are all i.i.d., then
$$
\mathbb E\left[ \frac 1n \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - Z_i) \right) \right] = \frac 1n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(\theta+\epsilon) - \theta \right) = \varepsilon.
$$
So this is the simplest unbiased estimator you could come up with:
$$
\widehat{\varepsilon} = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - Z_i). 
$$
It will have a variance, namely since $\mathrm{Var}(Z_i) = \theta(1-\theta)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_i) = (\theta + \varepsilon)(1-(\theta + \varepsilon))$, thus
$$
\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-Z_i) \right) = \frac 1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var}(X_i) + \mathrm{Var}(Z_i) \\
= \frac 1{n^2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (\theta+\varepsilon)(1-\theta-\varepsilon) + \theta(1-\theta) \right) \\
= \frac 1n \left( 2\theta(1-\theta) + \varepsilon(1-\theta) + \theta(1-\varepsilon) - \varepsilon^2 \right).
$$
Hope that helps,